# Aligning label and custom checkbox

Tags: html, css

How do I align a label and a custom checkbox? The code snippet is below. I want to make sure that the label and switch are vertically aligned and I should also have the ability to use any text in the label. I cannot use the `position:absolute` method to align the label since the text might change and I dont want any overlap.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #999;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: green;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"]:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 16.66667px;
  width: 16.66667px;
  top: 6.5px;
  right: 33px;
  border-radius: 11.11111px;
  background: #fff;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after {
  right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <label for="checkbox1">Test Test Test Test</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the vertical-align property on the input (ex: `vertical-align: middle;`):

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #999;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: green;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 16.66667px;
  width: 16.66667px;
  top: 6.5px;
  right: 33px;
  border-radius: 11.11111px;
  background: #fff;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after {
  right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <label for="checkbox1">Test Test Test Test</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
</div>
```